# Form validation through isValid method always return false on Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post

I have a form type for one of my entities, with one input field and the submit button. The form displays correctly at the view but the problem comes when I submit the form, the `$form->isValid()` always return false and I don't know the reason of that. I print the data of post request and my data is there and I also have another form type for another entity with which I haven't any kind of problem. And if someone could tell me how isValid() method works I will be grateful cuz I don't understand how this function considers something valid or invalid.

And here is the the code that I'm using:

The Controller's code:

```
public function commentAction(Request $request, $commentNumber){

    $com = new Comment();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $comment = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Comment')
    ->findById($commentNumber);

    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $com);

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $username = $user->getUsername();

    if($form->isValid()){
      $comment_object = $em->find('AppBundle:Comment', $commentNumber);

      $rep->setIdComment($comment_object);
      $rep->setUserReadReply('yes');
      $rep->setAdminReadReply('no');
      $rep->setReply($request->request->get('reply')['reply']);
      $rep->setUser($username);
      $em->persist($rep);
      $em->flush();
    }

    $comments = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Comment')
    ->findByIdComment($commentNumber);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    return $this->render('comments/see_comments.html.twig', array('comment' => $comment, 'comments' => $comments, 'form' => $form->createView()));
  }
```

The CommentType's code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('reply')
            ->add('send', 'submit');
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment'
        ));
    }
}
```

The Comment's Class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
* @ORM\Table(name="comments")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CommentRepository")
*/
class Comment {

  /**
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
  protected $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="posts")
  */
  protected $idPost;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
  */
  protected $user;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
  */
  protected $reply;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
  */
  protected $adminReadReply;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
  */
  protected $userReadReply;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idTicket = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param string $user
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set reply
     *
     * @param string $reply
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setReply($reply)
    {
        $this->reply = $reply;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get reply
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReply()
    {
        return $this->reply;
    }

    /**
     * Set adminReadReply
     *
     * @param string $adminReadReply
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setAdminReadReply($adminReadReply)
    {
        $this->adminReadReply = $adminReadReply;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adminReadReply
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdminReadReply()
    {
        return $this->adminReadReply;
    }

    /**
     * Set userReadReply
     *
     * @param string $userReadReply
     * @return Reply
     */
    public function setUserReadReply($userReadReply)
    {
        $this->userReadReply = $userReadReply;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userReadReply
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserReadReply()
    {
        return $this->userReadReply;
    }

    /**
     * Set idPost
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Post $idPost
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setIdPost(\AppBundle\Entity\Post $idPost = null)
    {
        $this->idPost = $idPost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idPost
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Post
     */
    public function getIdPost()
    {
        return $this->idPost;
    }
}
```

And in the see_comments.html.twig template, I have `{{ form(form) }}` (the rest of code there is just simple html)

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The handleRequest method grabs the POST’ed data from the request,
>   processes it, and runs any validation.

So, you must put :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

before

```
if($form->isValid())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using `{{ form(form) }}` to render the form, I added your code to my template but it still doesn't work. I tried render the template between form_start, form_end tags... but it doesn't work. I also checked if with my previous code the token was inside the form and yes, the token is there... Sorry if my question is stupid, but I'm learning Symfony and I'm stuck since yesterday with that stuff... @Soufiene

Comment: $form->handleRequest($request); must be before if($form->isValid()).

Comment: Damm, I feel so stupid right now. Big fail and now it works. If you update your answer I will mark it as valid. And thanks again I didn't so that fail

Comment: Sorry for the delay in mark it as valid. I couldn't connect before